# Artifactory yum install 404 error

Tags: artifactory, yum

I am currently running an instance of Artifactory Professional 4.0.2 rev 40009 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have configured https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au as a remote Yum repository in Artifactory.

I have configured yum on a linux server to point to this artifactory instance.

When I run the command :

```
yum install -y epel-release
```

I get 404 errors like this :

```
epel/7/x86_64/updateinfo       FAILED
http://<Artifactory Server Instance>/artifactory/mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/0dd9044655fe1722d6579c768395f719a74f9954cf78e80d0b757a313be4f7e2-updateinfo.xml.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found|    0 B  --:--:-- ETA Trying other mirror.
```

If I browse the url directly I get a similar 404 error :

```
{
    "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Not Found"
    } ]
}
```

Remote Yum Repo Configuration in Artifactory :

```
<remoteRepository>
        <key>mirror.aarnet.edu.au</key>
        <type>yum</type>
        <description>Mirror of Yum packages hosted by mirror.aarnet.edu.au</description>
        <includesPattern>pub/centos/**,epel/**,pub/epel/**,pub/elrepo/**,pub/el6-dom0/**,pub/fedora/**,pub/fedora-secondary/**,</includesPattern>
        <repoLayoutRef>simple-default</repoLayoutRef>
        <dockerApiVersion>V1</dockerApiVersion>
        <forceDockerAuthentication>false</forceDockerAuthentication>
        <blackedOut>false</blackedOut>
        <handleReleases>true</handleReleases>
        <handleSnapshots>true</handleSnapshots>
        <maxUniqueSnapshots>0</maxUniqueSnapshots>
        <suppressPomConsistencyChecks>true</suppressPomConsistencyChecks>
        <propertySets>
            <propertySetRef>artifactory</propertySetRef>
        </propertySets>
        <archiveBrowsingEnabled>false</archiveBrowsingEnabled>
        <url>https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au</url>
        <offline>false</offline>
        <hardFail>false</hardFail>
        <storeArtifactsLocally>true</storeArtifactsLocally>
        <fetchJarsEagerly>false</fetchJarsEagerly>
        <fetchSourcesEagerly>false</fetchSourcesEagerly>
        <retrievalCachePeriodSecs>0</retrievalCachePeriodSecs>
        <assumedOfflinePeriodSecs>300</assumedOfflinePeriodSecs>
        <missedRetrievalCachePeriodSecs>7200</missedRetrievalCachePeriodSecs>
        <remoteRepoChecksumPolicyType>generate-if-absent</remoteRepoChecksumPolicyType>
        <unusedArtifactsCleanupPeriodHours>24</unusedArtifactsCleanupPeriodHours>
        <shareConfiguration>false</shareConfiguration>
        <synchronizeProperties>false</synchronizeProperties>
        <listRemoteFolderItems>true</listRemoteFolderItems>
        <rejectInvalidJars>false</rejectInvalidJars>
        <allowAnyHostAuth>false</allowAnyHostAuth>
        <socketTimeoutMillis>15000</socketTimeoutMillis>
        <enableCookieManagement>false</enableCookieManagement>
        <enableTokenAuthentication>false</enableTokenAuthentication>
        <proxyRef>Developer-Proxy</proxyRef>
</remoteRepository>
```

Yum Repo Configuration :

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://<artifactory server instance>/artifactory/mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Debug
baseurl=http://<artifactory server instance>/artifactory/mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/debug
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://<artifactory server instance>/artifactory/mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/epel/$releasever/SRPMS
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1
```

Zapping the Cache and Deleting the content of the remote repository in Artifactory fixes the issue, but it keeps recurring, we're looking for a permanent fix.

How do I fix this issue?

Output of failed binary url ?trace :

```
Request ID: 11bb6581
Repo Path ID: mirror.aarnet.edu.au:pub/centos/7/updates/x86_64/repodata/1d3ddc7dc7e6b67102e2dec1e43813582e2de2d1c813007350586aee0e32eb2e-primary.sqlite.bz2:
Method Name: GET
User: <UserName>
Time: 2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00
Thread: http-nio-8082-exec-28
Steps: 
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Received request
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Request source = 10.62.58.23, Last modified = 01-01-70 09:59:59 +10:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-nio-8082-exec-28
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Exiting download process - intercepted by addon manager
```

Comment: How did you configure your remote repository? How did you configure your yum?

Comment: @JBaruch Thanks for your response, I have updated the question with the info

Comment: Looks good at the first glance. Please try to paste the url in the brower and see if it's still 404? And if it is, please add `?trace` to the end of the URL and take a look at the result.

Comment: @JBaruch I have since zapped the cache and deleted content. I'll keep an eye on it and if it occurs again for the repo I'll browse the url with `?trace` and post it here.

Comment: Issue started occuring again today with the same repository, it's been 2 weeks since I last zapped the cache and deleted content for this repo. Trying to do "yum install -y epel-release" it's bombing out with "....primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found". If I browse the url with ?trace on the end of it the output is :

Comment: Request ID: 11bb6581
Repo Path ID: mirror.aarnet.edu.au:pub/centos/7/updates/x86_64/repodata/1d**2e-primary.sqlite.bz2:
Method Name: GET
Time: 2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00
Thread: http-nio-8082-exec-28
Steps: 
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Received request
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Request source = 10.62.58.23, Last modified = 01-01-70 09:59:59 +10:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-nio-8082-exec-28
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2016-02-02T13:56:45.565+11:00 Exiting download process - intercepted by addon manager

Comment: I ** out some of the cache guid so I could fit it all in one comment without going over character limit

Answer (score 0):

This problem has re-occurred after an upgrade to v5.1.4. The cache retention period was reduced to 10secs in the hope that it would increase the likelihood that the index files update correctly but it has had no effect and we have to delete the contents of the repodata folder and zap the cache as a work-around.

I can see that the hash of repomd.xml on http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (last modified: 29-Mar-2017 18:05) doesn't match the hash of the same file within Artifactory (last modified: 29-Mar-2017 05:05). The file sizes also don't line up.

This is causing certain yum installs to fail due to the out of date index files -

```
yum update -y && yum clean all
 ---> Running in e154e2b58ab1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package binutils.x86_64 0:2.20.51.0.2-5.44.el6 will be updated
---> Package binutils.x86_64 0:2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1 will be an update
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-52.el6 will be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-53.el6_9 will be an update
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.192.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.209.el6_9.1 will be an update
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.192.el6 will be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.209.el6_9.1 will be an update
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-52.el6 will be updated
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-53.el6_9 will be an update
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.21.0-8.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.28.3-3.el6_9 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: nspr >= 4.13.0 for package: nss-3.28.3-3.el6_9.x86_64
---> Package nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.21.0-8.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.28.3-3.el6_9 will be an update
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.21.0-8.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.28.3-3.el6_9 will be an update
---> Package nss-util.x86_64 0:3.21.0-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package nss-util.x86_64 0:3.28.3-1.el6_9 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: nspr >= 4.13.0-1 for package: nss-util-3.28.3-1.el6_9.x86_64
---> Package tzdata.noarch 0:2016f-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package tzdata.noarch 0:2017b-1.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nss-3.28.3-3.el6_9.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: nspr >= 4.13.0
           Installed: nspr-4.11.0-1.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS/6.8)
               nspr = 4.11.0-1.el6
Error: Package: nss-util-3.28.3-1.el6_9.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: nspr >= 4.13.0-1
           Installed: nspr-4.11.0-1.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS/6.8)
               nspr = 4.11.0-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Trace output doing a HTTP GET to http:///org.centos.mirror/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml?trace

```
Request ID: 848754bb
Repo Path ID: org.centos.mirror:6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Method Name: GET
User: anonymous
Time: 2017-04-20T10:17:28.591+10:00
Thread: http-nio-9081-exec-130
Steps: 
2017-04-20T10:17:28.591+10:00 Received request
2017-04-20T10:17:28.591+10:00 Request source = x.x.x.x, Last modified = 01-01-70 09:59:59 +10:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-nio-9081-exec-130
2017-04-20T10:17:28.591+10:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:17:28.591+10:00 Retrieving info from {} repository '{}' type 
2017-04-20T10:17:28.623+10:00 Found the resource in the cache - checking for expiry
2017-04-20T10:17:28.623+10:00 Returning resource as expired
2017-04-20T10:17:28.623+10:00 Executing any AltRemotePath user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:17:28.623+10:00 Appending matrix params to remote request URL
2017-04-20T10:17:28.623+10:00 Using remote request URL - http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
2017-04-20T10:17:28.623+10:00 Executing HEAD request to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Found remote resource with last modified time - Wed Mar 29 05:05:42 AEDT 2017
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Found remote resource with ETag - "ea5-54bce4edce980"
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Found remote resource with content length - 3749
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Returning found remote resource info
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Requested resource is found = true
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Request is HEAD = false
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Request is for a checksum = false
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = false
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Responding with found resource
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Executing any AltResponse user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Alternative response status is set to -1 and message to 'null'
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Found no alternative content handles
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Retrieving a content handle from target repo
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 The requested resource isn't pre-resolved
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Target repository isn't virtual - verifying that downloading is allowed
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Creating a resource handle from 'org.centos.mirror'
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Target repository is configured to retain artifacts locally - resource will be stored and the streamed to the user
2017-04-20T10:17:28.654+10:00 Remote repository is online
2017-04-20T10:17:28.685+10:00 Found the resource in the cache - checking for expiry
2017-04-20T10:17:28.685+10:00 Returning resource as expired
2017-04-20T10:17:28.685+10:00 Found expired cached resource but remote is newer = false. Cached resource: 1490724342000, Remote resource: 1490724342000
2017-04-20T10:17:28.685+10:00 Force expiration on the cached resource = false
2017-04-20T10:17:28.685+10:00 Resource isn't cached and isn't expired = false
2017-04-20T10:17:28.685+10:00 Found expired cached resource and is newer than remote = true
2017-04-20T10:17:28.685+10:00 Executing any AltRemotePath user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:17:28.716+10:00 Found the resource in the cache - checking for expiry
2017-04-20T10:17:28.716+10:00 Found request parameter {}=artifactory.forceDownloadIfNewer
2017-04-20T10:17:28.716+10:00 Returning resource as expired
2017-04-20T10:17:28.716+10:00 Using remote request URL - http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:properties
2017-04-20T10:17:28.716+10:00 Executing HEAD request to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:properties
2017-04-20T10:17:28.732+10:00 Received status 404 (message: Not Found) on remote info request - returning unfound resource
2017-04-20T10:17:28.732+10:00 Found no remote properties
2017-04-20T10:17:28.763+10:00 Un-expiring cached resource if needed
2017-04-20T10:17:28.763+10:00 Is resource metadata = false
2017-04-20T10:17:28.763+10:00 Un-expiring the resource
2017-04-20T10:17:28.810+10:00 Found the resource in the cache - checking for expiry
2017-04-20T10:17:28.810+10:00 Found request parameter {}=artifactory.forceDownloadIfNewer
2017-04-20T10:17:28.810+10:00 Returning cached resource
2017-04-20T10:17:28.810+10:00 Removing the resource from all failed caches
2017-04-20T10:17:28.810+10:00 Returning the cached resource
2017-04-20T10:17:28.810+10:00 Creating a resource handle from 'org.centos.mirror-cache:6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml'
2017-04-20T10:17:28.825+10:00 Identified requested resource as a file
2017-04-20T10:17:28.825+10:00 Requested resource is an ordinary artifact - using normal content handle with length '3751'
2017-04-20T10:17:28.825+10:00 Executing any BeforeDownload user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:17:28.825+10:00 Responding with selected content handle
2017-04-20T10:17:28.825+10:00 Request succeeded
```

edit: I noticed synchronise properties was configured on the repository. After disabling the option, the trace output is now as below. Seems like the timestamp for the cached repomd file, and the remote are identical, however the file contents are differ (revision number in mirror.centos.org is 1463896289, but in Artifactory is showing as 1490724196).

```
Request ID: a4f6fc65
Repo Path ID: org.centos.mirror:6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Method Name: GET
User: fowliena
Time: 2017-04-20T10:56:03.880+10:00
Thread: http-nio-9081-exec-133
Steps: 
2017-04-20T10:56:03.880+10:00 Received request
2017-04-20T10:56:03.880+10:00 Request source = x.x.x.x, Last modified = 01-01-70 09:59:59 +10:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-nio-9081-exec-133
2017-04-20T10:56:03.880+10:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:56:03.880+10:00 Retrieving info from {} repository '{}' type 
2017-04-20T10:56:03.912+10:00 Found the resource in the cache - checking for expiry
2017-04-20T10:56:03.912+10:00 Returning resource as expired
2017-04-20T10:56:03.912+10:00 Executing any AltRemotePath user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:56:03.912+10:00 Appending matrix params to remote request URL
2017-04-20T10:56:03.912+10:00 Using remote request URL - http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
2017-04-20T10:56:03.912+10:00 Executing HEAD request to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Found remote resource with last modified time - Wed Mar 29 05:05:42 AEDT 2017
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Found remote resource with ETag - "ea5-54bce4edce980"
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Found remote resource with content length - 3749
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Returning found remote resource info
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Requested resource is found = true
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Request is HEAD = false
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Request is for a checksum = false
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = false
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Responding with found resource
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Executing any AltResponse user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Alternative response status is set to -1 and message to 'null'
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Found no alternative content handles
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Retrieving a content handle from target repo
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 The requested resource isn't pre-resolved
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Target repository isn't virtual - verifying that downloading is allowed
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Creating a resource handle from 'org.centos.mirror'
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Target repository is configured to retain artifacts locally - resource will be stored and the streamed to the user
2017-04-20T10:56:03.943+10:00 Remote repository is online
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Found the resource in the cache - checking for expiry
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Returning resource as expired
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Found expired cached resource but remote is newer = false. Cached resource: 1490724342000, Remote resource: 1490724342000
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Force expiration on the cached resource = false
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Resource isn't cached and isn't expired = false
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Found expired cached resource and is newer than remote = true
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Remote property synchronization is disabled - expired resource property synchronization not attempted
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Un-expiring cached resource if needed
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Is resource metadata = false
2017-04-20T10:56:03.974+10:00 Un-expiring the resource
2017-04-20T10:56:04.005+10:00 Found the resource in the cache - checking for expiry
2017-04-20T10:56:04.005+10:00 Found request parameter {}=artifactory.forceDownloadIfNewer
2017-04-20T10:56:04.005+10:00 Returning cached resource
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Removing the resource from all failed caches
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Returning the cached resource
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Creating a resource handle from 'org.centos.mirror-cache:6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml'
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Identified requested resource as a file
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Requested resource is an ordinary artifact - using normal content handle with length '3751'
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Executing any BeforeDownload user plugins that may exist
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Responding with selected content handle
2017-04-20T10:56:04.021+10:00 Request succeeded
```

Comment: This seems more like a question. Please refer to [answer]